# Xamarin.Forms Azure Push Notifications - "MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: You do not have permission to view this directory or page"

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to implement push notifications in my Xamarin.Forms app.
I've followed [this Microsoft doc](http://MobileServiceInvalidOperationException:%20You%20do%20not%20have%20permission%20to%20view%20this%20directory%20or%20page), but am getting an `Unauthorized` error on the

```
await push.RegisterAsync(RegistrationID, templates);
```

line. Exception is as follows:
`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: You do not have permission to view this directory or page.`

I have added the `Sender ID` (from Firebase) (they call it the "project number" in the docs)

```
public class PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver : GcmBroadcastReceiverBase<GcmService>
{
    public static string[] SENDER_IDS = new string[] { "<my_sender_id_here>" };
}
```

I have also added the `Server key` (from Firebase) to the "Google (GCM) API Key" in my Notification Hub in the Azure portal.

I have signed in to a Google account on my AVD. (I've also signed in to the Azure MobileServicesClient using Azure AD B2C, but I don't think that matters here.)

I have found [other people with this same issue](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/thewindowsazureproductsite/add_push_notifications_to_your_xamarinandroid_app/) (search for "permission", direct linking is not working), but only one instance of it. And nobody provides the solution.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you just haven't seen any of my replies as I have answered this half a dozen times.

There is currently an issue with App Service Push.  The fix needs to be rolled out across Azure App Service, so it isn't going to be quick.

Instead, take a look at Chapter 5 of my book at http://aka.ms/zumobook - it provides the exact alternate code that you need.  The code provided will work after the fix as well as now, so it's not like your code is going to have to change again.

Comment: Can't say that I have come across any of them. Classic Google. Thanks! I'll try it out!

Comment: This worked for me. I used the alternate code (`client.InvokeApiAsync<DeviceInstallation, DeviceInstallation>(...)` method instead of the `push.RegisterAsync(...)).  Thanks Adrian!

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a more plausible solution. As we were all following the tutorial on Mobile Apps we've added authentication to our backend. When registering for push notification with our device we didn't authenticate first so all our device registrations fail (and didn't show up in the 'Device Registrations' tab of our hub (in Visual Studio). Changing the option 'Action to take when request is not authenticated' to 'Allow Anonymous requests (no action)' did the trick! Devices are showing up and push notifications are send!